# What is the best CLIENT side solution for a real-time GPS tracking system (corelocation, geolocation)

Tags: android, iphone, ios, geolocation, gps

I need to track several devices' location (iPhone/Galaxy).
I want them to send me their latitude/longitude every several seconds OR when there's a significant (few meters) location change.
By sending I mean an HTTP request to my server. Websocket is possible.

**The solution I'm looking for is 3rd party, i.e something similar to [Pushover](https://pushover.net) and [UrbanAirship](http://urbanairship.com) (those are 3rd party push notification providers).**

That's it, a really simple app for iPhone/Galaxy in which the user configures a URL I'll provide him to which the app reports the location.

As for server side - I'm all set.

Comment: Please explain close-votes. This question is about a part of bigger PROGRAMMING project.

Answer (score 2):

For iPhone you have to check the services offered by Apple. I do not use iPhones and I cannot help you.

For Android, you can use the services provided by the LocationManager:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/index.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/index.html

http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/42.html

See [requestLocationUpdates](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) and [locationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) in particular.

You can register with the location manager to get location updates. After that, just send the new coordinates to your server with a GET or PUT HTTP call.

Comment: thank you for replying my "debated" question :) Well, my question aims for a "higher" answer, I mean I do not want to get into programming, instead I'd like to have an app which sits in the background and simply sends lat/long updates to a specific URL that the user (device owner) will set. Dead simple.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know of any (Android) app that can be used in this way. I even doubt there is one. Anyway, if you prefer not getting your feet wet with programming, you can easily find people willing to do it for your for a reasonably small amount of money. Have a look at e-lance, for example: https://www.elance.com/ .